# Simply connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis

Theorem: If a function f is analytis throughout a simply connected domain D, then for every closed contour C lying in D, the integral is o along the contour.

This is a theorem from the text I am using without complete proof. The problem is that when the closed contour has an infinite number of self-intersection points. Who can give me a rigorous proof or a reference about it?

Thanks

Comment: Rudin's _Real and Complex Analysis_ gives a rigorous argument that does not break down under infinite self-intersection.

Comment: @Akhil Mathew: On what page?

Comment: It's somewhere in the chapter on elementary properties of holomorphic functions (#10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a proof in [Section IV.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&lpg=PP1&dq=conway%20complex&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false) of J.B. Conway's *Functions of one complex variable*.